# Change Location After video is finished

Tags: javascript, redirect, video, replace, location

I want this video to automatically play, once the video is finished playing, I want to have it redirect to another page, completely automatic. WITH NO CLICKING OR ANYTHING. How do I do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>eve_</title>
<link rel="icon" rel="preload" href="images/evecircle.png" />
<style>

#video {
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-top:-10px;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<script src="text/javascript">

function playVideo(){
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.play();
    video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
       location.replace('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582133/no-idea-where-to-put-settimeout/49582203?noredirect=1#comment86172507_49582203'),
    });
}
</script>

<video controls id="video"  width="1300px" height="auto" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="images/shorteve.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you call `addEventListener` after your HTML loaded (inside `DOMContentLoaded` event).

When calling `document.getElementById('video')` outside `DOMContentLoaded` event mostly it will return `null`.

> The `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired when the initial HTML document has
>   been completely loaded and parsed

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  
  console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  var video = document.getElementById('video');

  video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    console.log("The video has ended");
    alert("The video has ended");
    //location.replace('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582133/no-idea-where-to-put-settimeout/49582203?noredirect=1#comment86172507_49582203');
  });
});
```

```html
<video controls id="video" width="200px" height="auto" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay">
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
```

Comment: But this is not redirecting the user to another site. This is just producing an alert

Comment: Just uncomment the redirect line and remove the alert line

Comment: Welcome, Please consider as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add an `eventListener` and then call your function when that is triggered.

```js
<script type = 'text/javascript' >
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  video.play();
  video.addEventListener('ended', onVideoFinished, false);

function onVideoFinished() {
  window.location.replace('...');
} </script>
```